Azure/Entra and Exchange online sync issues
I have modify SMPT address on on-premises on AD and running sync but the changes are not replicating in exchange online. Whiles the changes are reflecting in entra portal, it seems there is some issue with exchange online. Any idea while this changes not syncing properly?
I have run a Delta sync and still seeing the issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
